# Trouble updating html with JSON data from API using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am trying to build a random quote machine using an this api: https://market.mashape.com/andruxnet/random-famous-quotes

here is my JS

```
var second = new function() {
    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-Mashape-Key': '3VGdwZHnCqmshmfxz0pqt0388GZ0p1Ahg2DjsniAt12zxxJLpF',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/cat=movies',
      sucesss: function(response) {
        var ape = JQuery.parseJSON(response)
        var quoteText = ape.quote;
        var quoteAuthor = ape.author;

        $('#AJ').click(function (quoteText, quoteAuthor){
          $(".quoteText").html(quoteText);
          $(".quote-author").html(quoteAuthor);
      });
    }
    });
  };

$(document).ready(second);
```

I am trying to get the JSON to update the DOM on every click.

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always include a detailed description of your problem, describing the expected behaviour of your code and make sure to include any errors you get. As it is now, it's not clear, what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes two parameters, but it is bound to an element which will not provide those parameters, or at the least, not the information you are looking for it to provide.

What you actually want is for your onclick to call the ajax, and populate the inner html using the response.

```
$('#AJ').click(function (){
        $.ajax({
          headers: {
            'X-Mashape-Key': '3VGdwZHnCqmshmfxz0pqt0388GZ0p1Ahg2DjsniAt12zxxJLpF',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
          url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/cat=movies',
          sucesss: function(response) {
            var ape = JQuery.parseJSON(response)
            var quoteText = ape.quote;
            var quoteAuthor = ape.author;
            $(".quoteText").html(quoteText);
            $(".quote-author").html(quoteAuthor);

          }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you're initially making your request, and then triggering a click event to change the text to the already fetched values.  You need to restructure your code to send the request on click and then update the text when you get your response back.  The is most easily achieved by passing a callback function to your request.

```
function requestNewQuote(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-Mashape-Key': '3VGdwZHnCqmshmfxz0pqt0388GZ0p1Ahg2DjsniAt12zxxJLpF',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/cat=movies',
    sucesss: callback
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AJ').click(function () {
    requestNewQuote(function(response) {
      var ape = JQuery.parseJSON(response)
      $(".quoteText").html(ape.quote);
      $(".quote-author").html(ape.author);
    });
  });

});
```